# Windows batch - ask for user input with default value

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

In a windows batch file I want to ask the user for an input,
I want to show the user a default value which is the folder where the bat file reside.
So when running the batch file the batch check the current folder and set the default variable to it then user can accept the suggested value by clicking on enter or enter a different value.
i tried this code but it doesn't work, the UserInputPath is not set.

```
    set default=ABCD
    set /p UserInputPath=%default%
    echo %UserInputPath%
```

Comment: :-) if none selected use the default

Comment: See answer below then.

Comment: Replace the first line by `set UserInputPath=ABCD`, so when the user just confirms the prompt with {ENTER}, `ABCD` will be echoed. If you want the prompt to be prefilled with `ABCD`, then you need to use some external software that is capable of sending keystrokes to this prompt...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the first line by `set UserInputPath=ABCD`, so when the user just confirms the prompt with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the former variable value is not going to be overwritten and so `ABCD` is going to be echoed:

```cmd
set "UserInputPath=ABCD"
set /P UserInputPath="Prompt text: "
echo(%UserInputPath%
```

If you want to know whether the user typed anything, query the [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) value afterwards:

```cmd
if ErrorLevel 1 echo The user just pressed {Enter}.
```

---

N. B.:
If you want the prompt to be prefilled with `ABCD`, then you need to use some external software that is capable of sending keystrokes to this prompt...

Answer (score 10):

You asked for `user can accept the suggested value by clicking on enter or enter a different value`.

Take advantage of the behavior of `set /p`: if the input is empty (just `ENTER`), the variable keeps unchanged. So you can simply set a default value:

```
set "UserInputPath=ABCD"
set /p "UserInputPath=Enter path or just ENTER for default [%UserInputPath%] : "
echo %UserInputPath%
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on your edit of question. You want to use `%~dp0` to detect the drive and path of the batch file, then echo the path into the prompt and set it as default, unless a user types in something else, it will always use the default path the batch is run from. Can be run as `script value` or as `script` only where the user will be prompted:

```
@echo off
set "UserInputPath=%1"
set "default=%~dp0"
if "%UserInputPath%"=="" set /p "UserInputPath=Enter Path (Default "%default%"): " || set "UserInputPath=%default%"
echo "%UserInputPath%"
pause
```

Comment: Updated to always include the path of the batch file itself, as default value, as per edit of question.